# Recessed gum vs receding gum?

Tags: word-usage

Why do we say I have receding gum instead of saying I have recessed gum. I know receding is acting as a gerund, but if we have recessed , why do we have receding? Could you give more than one example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you are by the sea and the water is getting progressively lower: it is continuous process, so we use the present continuous:

> The tide is ebbing.

When it reaches the lowest point, just before the water starts to rise again, the process of ebbing has finished, so we can use present perfect:

> the tide has ebbed.

The situation with gums is the same, except gums don't ever reach an endpoint where they have fully receded and can go no further, so we describe a problem with our gums using the present participle **receding**.

If you google **receded gum**, you will find only references to **receding gum**.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recessed), **recessed** means "built in a space in a wall". It would be very unfortunate to have **that** happen to your gums.

This [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=receded%20gum%2Creceding%20gum%2C%20recessed%20gum&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creceded%20gum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creceding%20gum%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Creceded%20gum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creceding%20gum%3B%2Cc0) shows that references to **receded gum** or **receded gum tissue** used to be more common in old dental publications, but from about 1980 **receding gum** has been the most widely used term. It also shows that **recessed gum** never occurs. Here is a relatively recent reference to **receded gum**.

> ... and most patients with receded gum tissue do not even touch the gum line above the tooth. - *the hygiene professional: a partner in dentistry - 1999*

---

Note that, when we are talking about the condition of our gums, **receding** is a present participle- a kind of adjective.

Gerunds act as nouns, so you would only use this to talk about the process of receding. here is an example:

> Receding is an annoying thing that gums do.